# php custom array sort

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$myarray = Array (
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 1 
    [current] => 
)

[2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 2 
    [current] => 1 
)

[3] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 3 
    [current] =>
)

[4] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 4 
    [current] =>
)

[5] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 5 
    [current] =>
)
)
```

And I need to sort it, having the value **current** as the first, and the afterwards all the items that were **originally** after that current one, and the items that were originally **before** would be the last ones on the result array.

So the new array would look like this:

```
Array (
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 2 
    [current] => 1 
)

[2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 3 
    [current] =>
)

[3] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 4 
    [current] =>
)

[4] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 5 
    [current] =>
)

[5] => stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 1 
    [current] => 
)
)
```

It's very important that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the same order of element do not sort your array but rotate it until the current element is first, e.g.

```
while($myarray[0]['current']<>1) {
  array_push($myarray, array_shift($myarray));
}
```

Comment: Rotate instead of sorting, never would find it heehe Thanks a lot... Spot on!

Answer (score 4):

The [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) function may be of interest to you.

```
usort($input,function($a,$b) {return $a['current']-$b['current'];});
```

Comment: With that solution, the first array item would be my original last one. I need to keep the original order. Look at the IDs of my desired result

Comment: Hmm... in that case you should probably use a `foreach` to find the `current` entry, then [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) and [`array_unshift`](http://php.net/array_unshift) will help you get it to the front. If that's too complicated, consider reworking how the data is fetched in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with the [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

You basically set your custom order function and you pass it to usort() as the second parameter (the first one is the array to sort).

Inside the callback function you can define the way your array will be sorted. For example

```
usort($array_to_sort, function($a,$b) {
    return $a['current']-$b['current'];
});
```